# How to complete reinstalll phpunit using Synaptic

Tags: phpunit, 64-bit, ubuntu-12.04, pear

I am using ubuntu 12.04 64 bit OS and I have installed phpunit but not properly. I want to completely remove phpunit and its all pear packages from my PC and install it fresh again. Some command line help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try simply by uninstalling through pear

```
sudo pear uninstall phpunit/PHPUnit
```

You can also delete all of it's dependencies:

```
sudo pear uninstall phpunit/PHPUnit
sudo pear uninstall phpunit/DbUnit
sudo pear uninstall phpunit/PHP_CodeCoverage
sudo pear uninstall phpunit/File_Iterator
sudo pear uninstall phpunit/Text_Template
sudo pear uninstall phpunit/PHP_Timer
sudo pear uninstall phpunit/PHPUnit_MockObject
sudo pear uninstall phpunit/PHPUnit_Selenium
sudo pear uninstall pear.symfony-project.com/YAML
```